# Shell.Current.GoToAsync to xct:Popup results in error System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, popup, xamarin-community-toolkit

I would like to display a Popup with the Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup,  but I try to navigate to it using Shell I receive the error "System.NullReferenceException Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The xaml for my popup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xct:Popup 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
    x:Class="Restuco_Tables.Views.AddAreaPopup"
    Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
    Size="300, 300">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is a Popup!" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Popup>
```

The codebehind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AddAreaPopup : Popup
{
    public AddAreaPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I have registered Routing in AppShell:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AddAreaPopup), typeof(AddAreaPopup));
```

My call to the Popup using Shell:

```
private async void tbiNewArea_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/AddAreaPopup");
}
```

Comment: Who guaranteed that Popup could be cast to ShellNavigationState which is the type of the expected parameter of GoToAsync() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Shell Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#navigation-events), we can see that `Shell.Current.GoToAsync` need to ShellNavigationState type data, apparently popup page is not, so you have this error message.

If you use one simple ContentPage, having no problem.

So I suggest you can use [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) Popup Pages, then using `await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new Page2());` to go to PopupPage from one ContentPage in Shell.

```
private async void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new Page2());
    //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("page2");
       
}
```

Finally, to using `await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);` to close this popupPage.

```
private async void btnclose_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
}
```

Have xaml like this:

```
<popup:PopupPage
    x:Class="shellsample.Views.Page2"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            BorderColor="Black"
            CornerRadius="30">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                <Button
                    x:Name="btnclose"
                    Clicked="btnclose_Clicked"
                    Text="close" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</popup:PopupPage>
```

You will also need to init Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup in MainActivity.cs OnCreate method.

```
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);
```

You can also submit one feature in shell navigation on [Add support to Shell Navigation](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/441)